# Extract Strings based on sentences starting with Capital Letters?

Tags: python, regex

I have the following string:

```
JOHN SMITH, YOUTUBE: 
I'm having a great day today 
JANE DOE, GOOGLE:
I'm going to the gym later 
STEVE SMITH, FACEBOOK:
Time for people to speak 
SCHMEFF SCHMEZOS, JUNGLE:
Buy something from my online shop. You might like it
```

You can create the string here:

```
string =     """JOHN SMITH, YOUTUBE: 
    I'm having a great day today 
    JANE DOE, GOOGLE:
    I'm going to the gym later 
    STEVE SMITH, FACEBOOK:
    Time for people to speak 
    SCHMEFF SCHMEZOS, JUNGLE:
    Buy something from my online shop. You might like it"""
```

loading python packages:
`import re`

I am trying to find a regex to split the text based on the speakers and their sentence, so for example I am trying to get the following extract:

```
string1: JOHN SMITH, YOUTUBE>> 
I'm having a great day today 

string2: JANE DOE, GOOGLE>> 
I'm going to the gym later 

string3: STEVE SMITH, FACEBOOK>>
Time for people to speak 

string4: SCHMEFF SCHMEZOS, JUNGLE>> 
Buy something from my online shop. You might like it
```

Strings can span over multiple lines, so I am trying to capture two groups, the speaker who always has a colon : after there name (sometimes there is a whitespace so \s) and their speech can be on several lines.

I am trying to capture up until the next speaker, current regex is this:

```
(^[A-Z].*):\s*\n*(?=(?:[A-Z]|$))
```

Always names are in Capital letters and start when a new speaker talks, any help appreciated.

Am using Python 3.9

New sample string:

```
JOHN SMITH, GLOBAL HEAD OF YOUTUBE : Good morning, good 
afternoon, everyone . Before I hand over to facebook, I want to give a quick reminder of the reporting 
changes that have taken effect this filming of a tv show.  
 

 
BOBBY DUDE, GROUP FROM FACEBOOK:     Thanks, john smith lets talk about movies and films we watch when we are bored parents.
```

Comment: Now you have  the new speech on the same line as the speaker whereas originally the speaker and speech were on separate lines.

Comment: Yes - new update to reflect a different string set

Answer (score 2):

We can use `re.findall` here for a regex option:

```py
import re

inp = """JOHN SMITH, YOUTUBE: 
I'm having a great day today 
JANE DOE, GOOGLE:
I'm going to the gym later 
STEVE SMITH, FACEBOOK:
Time for people to speak 
SCHMEFF SCHMEZOS, JUNGLE:
Buy something from my online shop. You might like it"""
matches = re.findall(r'([A-Z]+(?: [A-Z]+)+, [A-Z]+):\n(.*?)(?=[A-Z]{2,}|$)', inp, flags=re.S)
print(matches)

[('JANE DOE, GOOGLE', "I'm going to the gym later \n"),
 ('STEVE SMITH, FACEBOOK', 'Time for people to speak \n'),
 ('SCHMEFF SCHMEZOS, JUNGLE', 'Buy something from my online shop. You might like it')]
```

Comment: I've added a new string, to test this application - see the updated post, as this is how strings appear:

Comment: You just changed your question.

Answer (score 2):

With re.split, split on a sequence of white-spaces that ends with a new line followed by an uppercase and no lowercase until the `:`.

```
import re

test = '''JOHN SMITH, YOUTUBE: 
I'm having a great day today 
JANE DOE, GOOGLE:
I'm going to the gym later 
STEVE SMITH, FACEBOOK:
Time for people to speak 
SCHMEFF SCHMEZOS, JUNGLE:
Buy something from my online shop. You might like it
JOHN SMITH, GLOBAL HEAD OF YOUTUBE : Good morning, good 
afternoon, everyone . Before I hand over to facebook, I want to give a quick reminder of the reporting 
changes that have taken effect this filming of a tv show.  
 
BOBBY DUDE, GROUP FROM FACEBOOK:     Thanks, john smith lets talk about movies and films we watch when we are bored parents.  '''

result = re.split(r'(?m)\s+(?=^[A-Z][^a-z:]*:)', test)
```